# Passing an arbitrary JSONValue to a JSNI function

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have a JSONValue in my Java that may be a JSONArray, a JSONObject, a JSONString, etc.  I want to pass it to a JSNI function that can accept any of those types.  If I naively write my JSNI as something like:

```
public final native jsni(Object parameter) /*-{
    doSomething(parameter);
}-*/;

public void useFunction(JSONValue value) {
    jsni(value);  //Throws js exception at runtime :(
}
```

then I get a javascript exception, because GWT doesn't know how to convert the JSONValue to a JavaScriptObject (or native string / number value).

My current workaround is

```
public final native jsniForJSO(Object parameter) /*-{
  doSomething(parameter);
}-*/;

public final native jsniForString(String parameter) /*-{
  doSomething(parameter);
}-*/;

public final native jsniForNumber(double parameter) /*-{
  doSomething(parameter);
}-*/;

public actuallyUseFunction(JSONValue value) {
  if (value.isObject()) {
    jsniForJSO(value.isObject().getJavaScriptObject());
  } else if (value.isString()) {
    jsniForString(value.isString().stringValue());
  } else {
    //etc
  }
}
```

This is a big burden for code maintainability, etc... *especially* if you have more than one parameter.  Is there a way to generate these functions automatically, or get around this issue altogether?  I've taken to wrapping everything in a JSONObject first, so I can definitely get a JavaScriptObject to pass to my jsni, but that's another clumsy mechanic.

Answer (score 2):

`JSONObject` is wrapping a native Javascript object, so you have to get that wrapped object before passing it to the jsni method.

```
  jsni(object.getJavaScriptObject());
```

Then in your jsni code you could handle the appropriate value:

```
  public final native jsni(JavaScriptObject parameter) /*-{
     doSomething(parameter.myproperty);
  }-*/;
```

[EDITED] To get the wrapped object of a `JSONValue` you have to call its `getUnwrapper()` method, but it is not public, so you have to call it from your jsni code:

```
private static native void jsni(JSONValue value) /*-{
  if (value) {
    value =  value.@com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONValue::getUnwrapper()()(value);
    alert(value);
  }
}-*/;
```

Comment: There is no such function, I'm afraid.  You can call `isObject().getJavaScriptObject()`, but not if the JSONValue represents a string, a number, or null.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONValue.html

Comment: Sorry I meant JSONObject instead of JSONValue, updated the comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a JSONValue, not a JSONObject.

Comment: Updated my response with an example to unwrap JSONValue